# NoSuchElement Exception while implementing Scanner Class

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

The main point to keep in mind that the time and space complexity should be minimal. So to achieve this, I combined two for loops in one, and then error `java.util.NoSuchElementException` occurred.

Error is on the following line : a = in.nextInt();

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int N = in.nextInt();
    int M = in.nextInt();

    long m[] = new long[N];
    long big=0; 

    int a = in.nextInt();
    int b = in.nextInt();
    int k = in.nextInt();

    int i;
    int j;
    for( i=0,j=a-1 ; i<M && j<=N  ; j++)
    {
            m[j] = m[j] + k;
            big = Math.max(big, m[j]);

        if(j==b-1)
        {
            a = in.nextInt();
            b = in.nextInt();
            k = in.nextInt();
            j = a-1;
            i=i+1;
        }
    }
    System.out.print(big);
}
}
```

The middle code that prior worked was as follows:

```
for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
    {
        int a = in.nextInt();
        int b = in.nextInt();
        int k = in.nextInt();

        for(int j=a-1;j<=b-1;j++)
        {
            m[j] = m[j] + k;
            if(m[j]>big)
            {
                big = m[j];    
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Because there's no element to read. The scanner has read as many ints as are available, and you're trying to read more.

Comment: Are you using an IDE to run this? In the command terminal this would have no issues running. It would just wait for keyboard input.

Comment: So you thought you would reduce complexity by hand-coding the inner for-loop via index manipulations? That is not helping.

Comment: There is a list of size 'x' initialized with zeroes. Have to perform 'y' operations on the list and output the max of final values of all the  elements in the list. Three integers a,b,c are given, and you have to add value c to all the elements ranging from index a to b (both inclusive).

Comment: What I thought is, would take first of set a,b,c outside loop and then make all conditions check in one statement and whenever 'a' reaches 'b' (By increment j++) would increment the value of i and also again set the value of j with next a and also update value of b for breaking the loop.

Answer (score 0):

What is the guarantee that m[a-1] exists, a is dynamic input and you are not checking whether it is >=0 and

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the root cause is in the loop test:

```
for( i=0,j=a-1 ; i<M && j<=N  ; j++)
```

Indeed the array is declared as:

```
long m[] = new long[N];
```

so the test should be:

```
 for( i=0,j=a-1 ; i<M && j<N  ; j++)
```